# Javascript workout error with array elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am curious to know how to get alert massage punting element number (Brazil is 6) from the array instead of of putting the name of the countries. I have tried in several ways but it is not working.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div></div>

</body>
```

Javascript :

```
var cleanCities = ["Argentina" , "Brazil", "Canada ", "Denmark"];
var visit = prompt("What is your city?");
var numLength = cleanCities.length;
var matchFound = false;

for (i=0; i<numLength ; i++) 
    if (visit === cleanCities[i]){

        matchFound = true;
        alert ("It is really a nice City")
        break;

    }

    if (matchFound === false){
        alert ("It is not in the List");
    }
```

Comment: You can use the value of i to point to the right index.. http://jsfiddle.net/hLs4f/ . Also avoid using alert to log the statements

Comment: I have no idea what *"...alert massage punting element number..."* means. Why is `Brazil` equated with `6`. I see no reason except for the number of characters in the word.

Comment: Brazil >6 letters , that is why it is 6

Comment: "I have tried in several ways" Can you show at least one of them?

Comment: @cookiemonster I think "punting" should be "putting". Then it makes sense.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: Yeah, sort of. I still couldn't tell how `Brazil` is `6`. And now he's saying it's greater than 6 letters, so who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clean up your braces and tabbing:

```
var cleanCities = ["Argentina" , "Brazil", "Canada ", "Denmark"];
var visit = prompt("What is your city?");
var numLength = cleanCities.length;
var matchFound = false;

for (i=0; i<numLength ; i++) {
    if (visit === cleanCities[i]) {
        matchFound = true;
        alert ("It is really a nice City")
        break;
    }
}

if (matchFound === false){
    alert ("It is not in the List");
}
```

---

---

To get the length of a string:

```
"Brazil".length
```

outputs: `6`

Comment: I know this one . I wanted that if I put 6 instead Brazil then it will response" It is  really a nice city" for brazil

Comment: To be clear: You will ask the user `prompt("What is your city?")`, and the user will type `6` into the box, and you will then respond with `alert ("It is really a nice City")`?

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think you are severely misunderstanding the problem

Comment: Solved, Thanks  @ Joe